# Is it possible to add a bounty without having enough reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, new-users

I'd like to put a bounty on my question, but I don't have enough reputation. How do I add a bounty under these circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have enough reputation... you can't make it a bounty question. That's rather the point of the restriction, isn't it? Like anywhere else that you spend some quantity for a service, if you have insufficient funds you can't get the service, plain and simple.

Comment: is there any thing like :Transfer Reputation between users 

IT might be good idea to do that ..

Comment: @joe If they're separate people... no. The point of reputation is to be earned, it isn't a resource for users to trade around willy-nilly. Wait for that user to give an opportunity to earn your upvotes, then they'll get reputation as a result.

Comment: Agreed; perhaps the fact that one uses reputation to "buy" bounties is causing more people to view rep as currency instead of a meritorious reflection of their contributions to the site?

Comment: Well, speaking about money, there is credit card allowing one to buy things even when he/she doesn't really have enough money.